# Show progress bar or spinner while KineticJS is drawing the stage

Tags: html, html5-canvas, kineticjs, preloader

Is there any way to display a progress-bar showing how long it will take for the whole canvas to load?

I have a HTML login area, wich (on success) executes a JavaScript-function to initiate the KineticJS-drawings.

On my desktop-pc it loads very quickly, so that any loader or progress-bar wouldn't be neccesary, but on mobile devices there shows a blank page up, as soon as I've submitted the login-information and it takes about 5-10 secs to load the stage.

Could I possibly fill this blank page with something, that shows the user that my page is still loading?

Comment: are you sure its the draw that is taking time or is it the network delays??

Comment: I would guess that the drawing is taking the time, because my script is only 32kb big and as I've said previously, the "loading"-time on my desktop-pc, which uses the same network as my iPad or smartphone, is barely noticeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You could show a "loading" .gif until your KineticJS project gets running**

Just layer a loading.gif under your canvas.

Then when your project is loaded, remove the gif.

Here's code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/YaU8W/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    #wrapper{
        position:relative;
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
    }
    #canvas{
        position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;
        border:1px solid green;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    #loading{
        position:absolute; top:50px; left:50px;
        border:1px solid gray;
    }
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    // Load your KineticJS project

    // After your KineticJS is loaded, remove loading.gif          
    // var element = document.getElementById("loading");
    // element.parentNode.removeChild(element);

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <img id="loading" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/loading1.gif" width=32 height=32></canvas>
        <canvas id="canvas" width=200 height=200></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I hope this is not a too dumb question, but how am I going to know when my KineticJS-project has finished loading? Is there something like a 'finished loading' event you could listen to?

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing your code ;)  I assume you do the usual ... create a stage, add layers,  create shape objects, wire up events.  Then at the end, you ask KineticJS to layer.draw() to display your app.  Since most of KineticJS is synchronous, if you remove the loading.gif after that last layer.draw, you'll be good.

Comment: You're right :) the problem is, that the last layer.draw() happens very quickly, which causes still the appearance of the unwanted white screen. Is there any way to check if the browser has finished rendering or loading? Btw: window.onload etc. doesn't really work as well...:(

Comment: Ok, I've got it now... I could hook into a ajax request and it works like a charm. Thanks @markE for your awesome support as always, keep it up! ;)